# Good base app for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Could anybody tell me a good base app for Rails 3?

Comment: A skeleton application with a couple of gems set up such as Devise, RSpec, ... .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

After doing a research, I think this is a great base app: https://github.com/dannymcc/BaseApp2

It provides the following:

- Layout
- Tabs
- Global links
- Optional sidebar
- Notice, warning and error flash messages
- Both a default stylesheet as well as a ‘clean’ one are included for easy layout development.
- Default dashboard page
- Administration panel where you can:
  Manage users (add, delete, purge, suspend, activate, send new passwords)
- Manage settings
- Manage site wide timed announcements
- Post-Commit Hooks ready to roll for Campfire, Basecamp, FriendFeed, Twitter and custom URL.
- User authentication, with password recovery and login recovery and account activation (by email)
- User Profiles:
  Location, Website, Full name fields by default, easily extendible.
  Gravatar for avatar support
- Mobile Ready
- Auto detect mobile users/visitors and display different views.
- Based on the JQTouch framework, making it easy to theme.
- Devise
- Declarative Authorization

Comment: It looks like BaseApp2 was last active about 1 year ago.  Is there a more current (as of 2013) alternative?

Comment: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer - very active, with 59 contributors

Answer (score 3):

Rails Wizard is a great way to build Rails apps.  Here's a reasonable template:

http://railswizard.org/ab97c24d59b6c172d1f4

Answer (score 0):

"Base rails 3 app with devise, rspec, cucumber, capybara, jquery, and machinist":
http://github.com/blatyo/rails3-base

Comment: Do you know how to install it? I've just donwloaded it (I'm using Ubuntu 10.04) and extracted it into a folder and then I ran bundle install and everything is ok. Now, I want to run the rails scaffold generator command but I get "undefined method  'hidden_namespaces' for Rails::Generators:Module (NoMethodError)". Do you know what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I actually never used it. I usually start from scratch :)